# google maps v2 cant force close

Tags: android, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

am trying to show a map on my android mobile.i checked some codes to so.even i got error.
This is the error i am having.

```
07-06 15:22:13.359: E/AndroidRuntime(10309):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
```

this is my activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

this is my layout

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my manifest file

```
    <permission
      android:name="com.android.softroniics.gmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.softroniics.gmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyApK21PhTXjmLuAQkigWWfXf1E1VS4ECIU"/>
```

please find me a solution to show asimple map,a tried a bunch of tutorials to show amap v2.
thanks in advance'

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ODFFl.png

Comment: show us your full manifest, xml layout and activity code

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your android map project?.

Comment: post your full code. whether your class extend activity or fragment activity . what's your min sdk version in manifest.

Comment: does your class extend `FragmentActivity`. pls post the full code.

Comment: Can you paste the full code + stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get Maps to work you need to follow a couple of simple steps. I'll try to summarize them here :

**- Add Google Play Services**

This is simply a matter of adding the library project and ensuring that the library project is properly exported.

There's an issue with ADT 22 that it sometimes "forgets" to export the libraries to your APK. You can verify this by going into your build settings and ensuring that the `Android Private Libraries` are checked. This will ensure that whatever is stored in your projects `libs` folder will be properly exported in your APK.

**- Decide your minimum SDK level.**

In order to use the new Google Maps V2 API on older devices we need to do 2 things

- use a SupportMapFragment instead of a MapFragment in your layout
- use a FragmentActivity instead of an Activity
- use the SupportFragmentManager instead of the FragmentManager in your FragmentActivity

**- Setup your maps key correctly**

Use the following overview to see if everything was setup correctly:

[image: Overview picture]

**- Interpret the stacktrace in LogCat**

This will tell you if you're dealing with a library issue (google play services not being included), or a maps API key issue (authorization issue)

**- Look at this guide + sample projects**

I've written up a post on how to setup a skeleton project. You can find it here : http://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part1

I've also created 2 skeleton projects using maps. You should be able to just clone them, change the API key and be on your way. I have one for older android versions (using the support library) and for newer android versions (using the native fragment)

https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

```
I had made sample code for map . hope this will help [Github Link](https://github.com/shujat89/myAndroidPractices.git)
```